# jquery problem with IE....works fine in firefox n chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a code which accept a query and uses yahoo websearch to return a suggestion.Its working fine in FF and Chrome . but in IE it gives no result. can any one help me on this??

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "dummyapi.php",
        data: {query: "yaho"},
        success: function(xml) { 
        alert($("Result",xml).text());
        /* do something here */ 
        },
        error: function(xhr, type, exception) { alert("Error: " + type); }
             });
});
```

#### dummyapi.php

```
$Squery = $_GET['query'];
$appid = "S8YhyGzV34HB2jaWxc9VsNIPqeeg0OwqV.WQ0IvF1lblZsUiFzlyEs12kVyH5_IT";
$u = "http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/spellingSuggestion?appid=".$appid."&query=".$Squery;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $u);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $xml = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            echo $xml;
```

Comment: Your updated code now has yet another syntax error in the declaration of $u, as = is outside the quotes and there's no . to concatenate. I pasted the exact code you have minus the syntax errors and it works.

Comment: Does IE give you an error of any kind?  Or does it just fail quietly?

Comment: i have all the syntax corrected. but no result in IE. it just give me an alert with no content in it.

Comment: i have edited the code in the question... hope it has correct syntax

Comment: @acrosman  no it does't gave me an error. just an alert box with no content...which is supposed to have a content

Comment: http://www.rootspot.com/stackoverflow/asdf.php - working for me...

Comment: @ Paolo :-   
I have tested the link u given... its working with FF. but not working with IE. it gives a alert with bank content....

Comment: Are you testing this on IE6 or IE7? It it working on IE7, tested on 3 computers at home...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're missing the closing }); of $.ajax, except if it's not shown there.

Answer (score 1):

Two quick things that are syntax errors:

- Missing the closing `});` of the ajax call (or document.ready, depending on how you look at it)
- Missing the closing " of the `$u` variable.

Just tested the code with these things fixed and it is working for me on IE, FF, Chrome.

Comment: i have the syntax corrected in my code. but doesn't works fine in IE. but no probelm wiht FF and chrome

Comment: do you have a syntax error in IE , in the bottom (status bar) ?